# How do I set timezone to UTC-8

Tags: linux, timezone

I need to set my timezone to UTC -8, I only see options to set to PST or GMT-8. Is there a way to make it show as UTC-8?

I am running RHEL6.

$ date
Sat Feb 23 01:41:41 UTC 2019

Comment: aren't UTC and GMT [the same](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html)?

Comment: Technically, they're not the same, per that link. UTC is a standard, rather than a timezone, so shouldn't actually be an option for the timezone. I do recall a disagreement decades ago, in which UTC supported leap seconds and GMT didn't, which made them be different by a few seconds, but that's been resolved as `TZ=GMT date; TZ=UTC date` reports the same time twice, apart from calling one GMT and one UTC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't said where you're setting this time zone, but you can invent any zone name you like in the `TZ` environment variable:

```
$ TZ='<UTC-8>+8' date
Fri Feb 22 19:25:36 UTC-8 2019
```

The `+8` is because POSIX, stupidly, [requires the offsets to be backwards](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03) (increasing westwards); the part in `<...>` is the displayed name and can be any single word. If it were purely alphabetic, the angle brackets wouldn't be required, but the `-` and `8` require them.

```
$ TZ='<yesterday>24' date
Fri Feb 22 03:30:15 yesterday 2019
$ TZ='tomorrow-24' date
Sun Feb 24 03:30:26 tomorrow 2019
```

If you're using a GUI or other zone-selection tool it is probably looking in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` for the zone definitions included in your system. If you want another zone to show up in that list, you would need to make a suitable zoneinfo file and copy it into place. The [`zic`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/zic) tool is used to compile zoneinfo files from [the textual format](https://linux.die.net/man/8/zic), which is relatively straightforward (particularly when just modifying an existing zone to change the name).

On some systems (but not, I think, Red Hat), there is a file `/etc/timezone` that globally sets the time zone as a name, and you can use that `TZ` variable format in that. Other systems use only `/etc/localtime`, which is conventionally a copy of one of the zoneinfo files, so you'd need to make a suitable file there too.

For per-user or -session zones, you can only use the environment variable.

---

If you set the zone to "`UTC-8`" or some other zone that isn't specifically defined, [it's treated as two things](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tzset.html#tag_16_629_06): first, a name for the zone ("UTC": whatever alphabetic string is there), and second an offset in POSIX orientation (whatever number is there). That means that `TZ=UTC-8 date` will output something like

```
Sat Feb 23 11:50:01 UTC 2019
```

- that is, it reports the time in China or Western Australia, and thinks the *zone is called "UTC"*. This behaviour is deeply confusing and annoying to track down when you make a typo. It may be the cause of the output you included in the question, but I can't tell.

This is being parsed as the traditional, mostly-obsolete, POSIX time zone format `RST6RDT5,M10.3.0/00:00:00,M2.4.0/00:00:00`, which includes optional names and offsets for standard and daylight time, and dates of changeover between the two. There are a lot of drawbacks to this approach for any non-trivial zone, and it doesn't track historical changes of definition in the way that the zone files do.

---

The "correct" thing to do is to use either the America/Los_Angeles zone, which displays as PST, or Etc/GMT+8 if you can't use the name or don't want daylight savings changes. GMT+8 displays the offset as "-08" with no textual label. Sometimes the supposedly-correct thing isn't good enough, and in that case one of the above should be ok.

Comment: Great answer! But I think you could improve it by adding a reference to explain this part: *POSIX requires the offsets to be backwards (increasing westwards)*, as your answer only states that without explaining it further.

Comment: The offset is defined as "[the value added to the local time to arrive at Coordinated Universal Time](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03)". There are also some concrete [examples in the `tzset` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tzset.html#tag_16_629_06).